# gulp, usemin and requireJS

Tags: gulp

I am using [gulp-usemin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-usemin) to minify and concat CSS and JS files and rename the references in the index.html. But my project also uses requireJS to load AMD modules from multiple files that are not referenced directly in the index.html and are not concatenated with the rest.

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<script src="js/libs/accounting.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/farbtastic.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/lz-string-1.3.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/color.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

How do I combine usemin with some other gulp plugin to make the requireJS files part of the output? The answer will probably contain something like [amd-optimize](https://www.npmjs.org/package/amd-optimize) but I do not understand yet how to combine this with gulp-usemin.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get this right, but it looks like you might want to use requireJS for all your JS-files and usemin only for your CSS.

If I look at your code I would add your lib-files to the `main.js` and remove them from your `index.html`. And later on use [gulp-requirejs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-requirejs) to create your build-js file.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

Usually I would try to check if the libs work with RequireJS and than integrate them using http://bower.io

require.config.js:

```
require.config({
    // List of all the dependencies
    paths: {
        jquery:     'bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        farbtastic: 'bower_components/farbtastic/src/farbtastic'
    },
    // Ensure that the dependencies are loaded in the right order
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        farbtastic: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
require(['main']);
```

main.js:

```js
require([
    "jquery",
    "farbtastic"
],
function() {
    $('#colorpicker1').farbtastic('#color1');
    $('#colorpicker2').farbtastic({ callback: '#color2', width: 150 });
});
```

This works for the [demo page of farbtastic](https://github.com/mattfarina/farbtastic/blob/master/demo/test.html) if you use RequireJS. The other libs hopefully can be used like this as well.
In this way you could combine all your JS using RequireJS.

Comment: The problem is those libs are not requireJS modules and I don't think it's possible to "include" JS libraries in JS file.

Comment: thanks, you get my upvote for the effort but this is not the way I want to go. Not all the libraries are AMD plugins and I don't want to treat them as such.

Comment: Ah well, I get it. Pity. Maybe it's worth checking AMD alternatives. Usually libs in bower support AMD and if not, most of the times there already is an issue opened up on github. I think it would be the nicer approach. But sounds like you're bound to this somehow.